# How do I bulk delete incompatible apps in iOS 11

Tags: iphone, ios

I finally upgraded to iOS 11 and when I go to Settings > General > About > Applications I have 105 incompatible apps listed.

Is there a way for me to delete all these in bulk?

I really don't want to have to go and find these apps one by one to delete them!

Comment: I highly suspect the answer will be "you can't". That's how things go on iOS—if Apple doesn't specifically add a feature to support a use case, that use case is impossible. Maybe there's some hidden functionality deep in the settings, but I doubt it.

Comment: I would love a follow on question explaining what the issue is. These apps don’t take up space on the device and you had them all before. Deleting them now means when the developer releases an update you will be able to resume automatically. Perhaps I’m missing the need to remove these, though.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there's no button to simply "Delete all 32-bit apps", but you can delete large numbers of apps quite quickly using iTunes.

This won't work with the latest versions of iTunes (12.7+), so if you've updated you will need to [download an older version](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1934).

1. Select your device next to the media type selection menu near the top of the screen.
2. Go to the Apps section.
3. For each app you would like to remove, click the X on its icon or find it in the list and click Remove. (iTunes won't show you which are incompatible there, but you can cross-reference with the list on your device and knock them out in a relatively speedy way.)
4. When you've finished, click the Apply button at the bottom right.

Answer (score 3):

Both iTunes 12.6.x and Apple Configurator allow management remotely from a computer. *As suggested in timothymh's answer*, but this is the perfect use case for the Offload Unused Apps feature.

This feature is designed to automatically remove apps you're not using. It's a low risk approach because even though the apps are removed, any documents and data are still kept in case you want to re-install the apps later (assuming they're still available/compatible).

To enable this feature, go to **Settings > iTunes & App Stores** and then swipe up to reveal the **Offload Unused Apps** option at the bottom. Tap the switch to enable it.

**NOTES:**

- I'm not exactly sure how this feature works when first enabled. More specifically, I don't know if once you've enabled it, it will wait a period of time to determine what apps you don't use, or whether it will check your past app usage to determine what you haven't been using.
- If it was me, and just to be on the safe side, I would use your iPhone for a while before enabling this. Or, depending on the number of apps you have installed, spend a day or so making sure you've opened all of them up (at least the ones you want to keep) and then enable this option.

Comment: I've never seen that option before. I guess if the apps are no longer compatible that I can't use them and so they become 'unused apps'. But then I may lose track of which other apps are uninstalled because I haven't used them in a while, and it's not like I can just go into iTunes to check.

Comment: Two things: (1) Yes, that's my thinking. Your 105 incompatible apps can't be used anymore and will therefore be deleted by enabling this option. It's not so much a *bulk delete* as much as an automated delete you don't have to think about! (2) As for worrying about losing track of other apps that may get *offloaded*, well, two things come to mind: (a) if they've been removed then you weren't really using them anyway, but (b) assuming they're still available, all you need to do is launch the App Store app and tap on your account icon (top-right) and then tap on Purchased > My Purchases.

Comment: Actually, the icon is still kept where it was, it's just greyed out with a little cloud icon next to its name. So if you need the app again, you  tap it and it will download. In the context of this question, that means there will still be over 100 app icons that are still present around the home screen, which you can't use and are taking up space. Personally, that would be unappealing to me, but YMMV.

Comment: Many of these apps have been deleted from the App Store as well. So do those apps get removed from the phone as well?

Comment: @Calion Just to clarify, are you asking that if you choose to enable the Offload Unused Apps feature, will iOS remove the app if it's no longer available in the App Store? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. Am I risking losing apps forever if I enable this option?

Comment: Hmm, well, if the app is no longer available on the app store for whatever version of iOS you have running, then it's most likely no longer compatible anyway. However, one way to protect yourself in the event an app is no longer available but would still work, is to in fact use iTunes 12.6.x or Apple Configurator to download the apps onto your desktop and ensure you have a backup regime in place (such as Time Machine) so that these apps are also backed up for future installation. Obviously, if you're using a PC then you'd have to go with the iTunes 12.6.x option instead.

Comment: Obviously the iTunes option may not be available forever, but then you've also got 3rd party software that can do this for you. One example: [iMazing](https://imazing.com/ios-app-management). Regardless of the option you use, the key aspect is having backups so that if/when the time comes, you have a copy of that old app (or .ipa file) that you can access to reinstall on your iOS device.

Comment: It is not at all true in my experience that apps are only pulled from the App Store when they become incompatible with the latest version of iOS. Several times I have discovered that an app I rely on is no longer on the App Store.

Comment: @Calion Yes, it certainly does happen. I guess I was just playing the odds, so to speak, that it's most likely. :) Another thing that does happen is that an app is no longer available for one version of iOS, but it is for other versions. Those other versions can be either older or newer versions, depending on the situation.

Comment: So do you in fact permanently lose access to an app that becomes no longer available on the App Store that has been offloaded unless you have backed it up with an older version of iTunes? This would seem to be a serious flaw in the feature, if true.

Comment: That's a worse case scenario and depends on the Developer. By default Apple's preference is to allow older versions to still be available. Developers have to configure settings for Last-Compatible versions. To quote Apple: *Some of your customers may not have a device that's compatible with your latest app version. To allow them to continue using your app, we make the last-compatible version of your app available to them.*

Comment: Apple then continues with: *If one or more of your app versions have significant usability or legal issues, such as infringement, deselect it below. This isn't recommended for any other reason. Any version you deselect won't be available for redownload from iTunes in the Cloud.* So, as you can see, the app should still be available unless the developer has actively removed it.  But yes, I do take your point that there is in a sense a bit of a *gap* here that requires filling, be it with iTunes, Apple Configurator or 3rd party software - although of course one should always have backups anyway!

Comment: You say "one should always have backups anyway," but to my knowledge there is no longer any way to back up the apps on your iDevices unless you use old versions of iTunes (or third-party software, I suppose).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Mac, you can download an app called ‘Apple Configurator 2’ where you can manage far more than you can/could in iTunes. Including bulk deleting apps.